# Magento 1.6.2.0 update to 1.9.x Now products have no category

Tags: database, magento-1.6, centos

> Magento ver. 1.6.2.0 with Template-Master Classic (f002) theme - modified

The update to Magento 1.9.x did not go well and I restored my backup to 1.6x.
Now none of the products have any category.

Specifically the question is "*Are the products in the expected category*?" *and the answer is no*.

All the category for existing products are gone and say (0) in the quantity. Further since the products both in the admin and front-end have no category, the fornt-end says "there are no products in this category" and the back-end looks like this:

[image: Poduct Category]

My problem description seems not to be anywhere to be found in any forum or help as everything seems to describe something close to an input error. I have **well over a few thousand products** so correcting them one by one would take me a year!!! I have looked in the database but I maybe don't know enough to see what is wrong or missing? I have many backups of the database but I do not know what table to import to correct this? And I do not want to loose my new inventory edits.

At one point I had a link as how to export and import just products but I can't find it as the last time I did something like this was Magento 1.4 something

thanks for your help

nilandtrading.com (formally nilandsplace.com)

Comment: Did you reindex after restoring?

Answer (score 0):

If you have backup of your previous database then find the table from backup - `catalog_category_product` here you can see all products and their categories.

So, rename the table and move to new updated magento database, and then create a custom php script and write sql query to retrieve info from backup table and update to new table.

Try this one, I hope this solves your problem.